# Eisenstein Series of a Dirichlet Character (generalizations)

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

For $\chi$ a primitive Dirichlet character modulo $N$ satisfying $\chi(-1)=-1$, we have the (normalized) Eisenstein series of weight 1
\begin{equation}\tag{a}
E_{1,\chi}(z) := \frac{N}{-4\pi i\,\tau(\overline{\chi})}\sum_{\substack{(n,m)\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}^2 \\ (n,m)\neq (0,0)}}\frac{\overline{\chi}(n)}{(n+mNz)},
\end{equation}

where $\tau(\overline{\chi})$ is the Gauss sum. We know that they are in $M_1(N,\chi)$ and have $q$-expansion

\begin{equation}\tag{b}
E_{1,\chi}(z) = L(\chi,0)/2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big(\sum_{d|n}\chi(d)\Big)q^n, \quad \text{where }q=e^{2\pi i z}.
\end{equation}

These series (and their generalization to other weights) are extremely important to number theory. My questions are:

$\textbf{1.}\;$ Let us suppose we have a primitive Dirichlet character with the "wrong" parity, $\chi(-1)=1$. In this case, $(a)$ simply adds up to $0$ (because the terms in the summation cancel out). However, can we still say something about the formal power series defined by $(b)$? I know it is not a modular form, but does it have any interesting properties? Is it of any relevance to number theory?

$\textbf{2.}\;$ Let us suppose our Dirichlet character $\chi$ satisfies $\chi(-1)=-1$, but is not primitive at level $N$ (say, it is of conductor $N'$). In this case, we can still define a series $E_{1,\chi}$ using $(a)$ at level $N$. But we could also define another series using $\chi^*$ (the primitive character attached to $\chi$), that is, we could consider the series $E_{1,\chi^*}$ defined by $(a)$ at level $N'$, and then regard it at level $N$ via the inclusion $M_1(N',\chi^*)\subset M_1(N,\chi)$. Notice $E_{1,\chi^*}$ and $E_{1,\chi}$ are related, but are not equal. For example, for each $t|(N/N')$ we have a different way to embed $E_{1,\chi^*}$ into level $N$, and we can write $E_{1,\chi}$ as a sum of these embeddings of $E_{1,\chi^*}$. So I wonder, is there a "correct" way to define the Eisenstein series of an imprimitive character? Is it $E_{1,\chi^*}$, $E_{1,\chi}$, or maybe something else? Whatever the definition is, do we still have the $q$-expansion given by $(b)$?

Comment: You are using that the discrete Fourier transform of a primitive character is (up to a Gauss sum factor) its complex conjugate. For non-primitive character there are additional terms.  More generally you can replace $\overline{\chi}$ in your Eisenstein series by any zero mean odd periodic sequence, in the $q$-series it will be its DFT which can be any odd periodic sequence.

Comment: I think the case $\chi(1)=1$ needs to replace the $q$-series by a Maass form expansion. The Dirichlet series $\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)$ still has a [functional equation but it involves two $\Gamma(s/2)$ factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maass_wave_form#Theorem:_The_L-Function_of_a_Maass_form) instead of one $\Gamma(s) = \Gamma(s/2)\Gamma(s/2+1/2)2^{2s-1}\pi^{-1/2}$ factor.

Comment: @reuns Many thanks!! I didn't know much about Maass forms. I went to check the wiki page you linked and learned a lot. Very interesting stuff! So, to clarify, for my question \textbf{1.} you mean that within the theory of Maass forms we can get some kind of weight 1 Eisenstein series of an even character? So in that case, we should replace $(b)$ by that, thus the original power series defined by $(b)$ is not useful? Also, my apologies, but I can't quite see the whole picture here yet, so I didn't understand how your comment about the the Dirichlet series $\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)$ is related to that.

Comment: That's what your question is about, the modular/automorphic/maass form associated to $\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)$

Comment: When $\chi$ is even, so that $\chi(-1) = 1$, then you get a weight *zero* Maass form, not weight one. For part (b), you might be interested in the theory of Eisenstein newforms and oldforms, which Matt Young has a very nice paper about.